# Trying to understand the space complexity of concatenated string output

Tags: python, algorithm, time-complexity, asymptotic-complexity, space-complexity

I had this problem in a coding interview:

```
# AAABB should return A3B2
```

This is a classic algorithm interview question. I said that I can solve this in `O(n)` time and `O(1)` space.

```
def compress(s):

    output = ''
    count = 1

    for i in range(len(s)-1):
        if s[i] == s[i+1]:
            count+=1
        else:
            output = output + s[i] + str(count)
            count=1

    output = output +s[i+1] + str(count)
    return output

compress('AAABB') #returns A3B2
```

I understand that `O(n)` space means that it grows proportionally with the size of input. So I was thinking that `O(n)` space would look something like
`[(A,3),(B,2)]`.

I am under the impression that `A3B2` is in `O(1)` space since it's not being split up into multiple strings.

I now realized that `n == len(s)` and my output grows un-proportionally (less) with my input size, so is it correct to say that space is `O(log n)`?

Comment: Wouldn't space be based on the number of unique characters in the string?  I'm just guessing here but I'd imagine they were hoping you would discuss whether or not you could do this transformation in place vs. creating a new string for the final result, etc.

Comment: If the input is `ABCDE` the output will be `A1B1C1D1E1`. So the worst case is O(n) space.

Comment: Also, you are thinking of constant space wrong.  For example, by simply allocating an output string you have exceeded O(1) space complexity

Comment: @jedwards He's only counting consecutive duplicates -- it's run-length encoding. So the alphabet size doesn't limit the result size.

Comment: @user3483203 Python strings are immutable, so you can't do in-place modification.

Comment: @Barmar I missed the consecutive part by skimming too fast, good catch.

Comment: `output = output + s[i] + str(count)` makes the time complexity `O(n^2)` because copying `output` is `O(n)`.

Comment: To fix that, you should make a list of all the counts, then use a list comprehension with `join` to concatenate them all (this uses internal buffers to avoid multiple copies).

Comment: If the character set is a fixed size then it's O(1) space. For example if the string is ASCII then there are a maximum of 127 values to output. So the asymptotic complexity is constant.

Comment: @samgak well you generalized it. What about my specific example?

Comment: I was wondering how my preferred way of achieving this (with itertools.groupy) would perform here, so i did https://repl.it/repls/CloseWhimsicalSubversion - but i have no clue how this would translate to a cost formula

Comment: O(1) space means that the output would take the same amount of space, regardless of the contents of the input string. That's clearly not the case.

Comment: @JimMischel big O notation describes the upper bounds

Comment: @samgak Yes, I know that. The OP said that he thought it was O(1). I was explaining why it's not. Your assertion that the character set defines the upper bounds is incorrect. The string `ABAB` is encoded as `A1B1A1B1`. So in the worst case the length of the output is twice the length of the input. The size of the character set is irrelevant.

Comment: @JimMischel yes you're right I misread the question as being a simple count of each character instead of a run length encoding

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The length of the output string you store must be counted.  In the worst case (no consecutive characters match), it’s actually twice as long as the input.  So clearly it’s *O*(*n*) in general: it would only be asymptotically better if somehow you knew that long inputs always contained very long runs.  (In the best case, all characters are the same, and the length of the one *number* is *O*(log *n*).)

That said, it’s sometimes useful to consider your output as a stream (like `print`), and then your space complexity (for `count` and perhaps the current input character) is constant.  Of course, even then it’s technically logarithmic, since the number of bits needed to store `count` is, but that’s often disregarded in practical analyses.